# varying write and read latency

Tags: c, sqlite

In my C application I am moving to SQLite DB.
Am doing experimentation on said DB.
I maintained 1 writer process and 3 reader processes.
Total records I have are 126220 (these are not read from a file; they are given to process at some point during the lifetime).

These are my observations.

1. When I have the following table structure (journal and synchronous set to OFF)

   ```sql
   create table if not exists table1(
       col1 int primary key,
       col2 text,col3 text ,col4 text,
       col5 BLOB
   )
   ```

   Write and read time taken is 25.814 seconds and 5.806 seconds respectively.
2. When I have the following table structure (journal and synchronous set to OFF )

   ```sql
   create table if not exists table1(
       col1 int primary key,
       col2 text,col3 text ,col4 text,
       col5 text
   )
   ```

   Write and read time taken is 70 seconds.

   Why is the difference here? I am assuming that it depends on the total bytes to write.
3. When single read is done time taken is 5 seconds, but if I do a parallel read the same is done in 3 seconds.

   Again why the difference here?
4. Can someone tell me how to serialize write.i tried using sqlite_busy_handler but i dint get any good examples of how to use? can someone please help me on this. Read and write operations are performed parallelly in my application

Comment: So the only difference between 1 and 2 is blob or text ? If you posted some code it would make it easier to help you. Also a dummy representation of your data. Keep same structure.

Comment: Data format is the set of characters of length between 800-4000.I just do bind to insert the data.

Comment: You must not use `int` but `integer` to [get a more efficient table structure](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid).

Answer (score 0):

Internally, SQLite handles UTF-8 text and blob values in exactly the same way, so any difference between 1. and 2. comes from how your program handles the data.

Concurrent reads are no problem (only writes need to be serialized); and SQLite caches data (and the OS, too). Typically, most of the time is needed for doing the actual I/O, so when you are doing two reads, the data needs to be read from disk only once. (Only the first thread to access a particular page needs to wait. With prefetching, the situation becomes more chaotic.)

Comment: the reads are done by 2 different processes it is not a multi threaded environment,so how does sqlite knows to perform I/O only once?
for write only change in code i did was using different function(bind_blob,bind_text_

Comment: The I/O is performed only once by the OS, to read the data into the OS cache.

Comment: if it is cached why the individual read takes more time? e.g i call read from one process after the first read is done i call second read? is it like data is stored in cache until a single read is finished?

Comment: I do not know what OS you're using or what its caching policies are.

Comment: Red hat linux 2.6.18-92.1.6.el5PAE

Comment: can you give me some ideas about how to serialize write

Comment: Just set a busy timeout value.